# Self Hosted Equivalent to Sendgrid / SES / Mandrill?

Tags: smtp, email, sendgrid, mandrill

Are there any self-hosted equivalents to Sendgrid, Mandrill, and other like services? With Mandrill, for instance, there are a number of features like bounce and open tracking, all exposed over a nice user interface. I'm looking for a similar technology, but one we could host in-house (I'm aware about the need to warm up IPs, etc). I found one solution called MessageGears but it looks like they're maybe more geared towards large enterprise implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with such in-house systems is that they either concentrate on the laborious task of sending out emails efficiently (and thus, lack a friendly interface) - or they do the opposite which is they have a very nice interface, but not as robust in the meat and potato department of sending messages out.

Ideally, you would want a combination of something like Sendy + a very fast email relay.  I can recommend [socketlabs](http://www.socketlabs.com/on-premise-options/) for the second part.

They have two main products - an assembly server (think of it like a very robust templating engine), and a MTA. Combine the two for your own hosted campaign management server.  Their MTA server is especially robust and full featured; and they have a comprehensive api as well.

I will warn you though - these products are designed as fast delivery engines, so unless you have a large volume of emails they may not be the best solution.  The second thing which I alluded to a bit is their interface; its not the best but it will get the job done; have a look at the [screenshots](http://www.socketlabs.com/on-premise-options/hurricane-mta-server/hurricane-mta-media/) and judge for yourself.

You'll have to build something on top of this yourself. Sendy is a good candidate to customize for this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I've heard of this solution a couple weeks ago:

http://sendy.co/

Comment: Yeah it turns out both MessageGears and Sendy use a cloud provider to actually send the mail. I'm hoping for a solution that allows us to send out of our own IPs.